# Far Manager NetBox SFTP can't connect to the linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, sftp, far-manager

I'm trying to connect to the RedHat Linux server through Far Manager 3.0.5800.0 x64 and NetBox plugin with SFTP. But it doesn't open the session as I expect it and doesn't exposure any errors. The connection screen blinks once and disappears, get me back to the NetBox: Stored sessions panel.

I CAN connect to that server through putty ssh, and it seems to be completely ok. I CAN connect through Far Manager to THAT server as a different user also as a root user.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I recently wrote in the .bashrc file some strings with "echo" command. And it seems to be after that the NetBox doesn't want to establish a session by that user.

So just inspect your .bashrc file and clean all echo commands.